# TextView not appearing in fragment

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with TextView in fragment. When the fragment is created the TV don't appear.
Here is the RelatorioPontos when I call the fragment that contains the TextViews:

```
public class RelatorioPontos extends FragmentActivity implements TabHost.OnTabChangeListener {

    private TabHost mTabHost;
    private HashMap<String, TabInfo> mapTabInfo = new HashMap<String, TabInfo>();
    private TabInfo mLastTab = null;

    private class TabInfo {
        private String tag;
        private Class<?> clss;
        private Bundle args;
        private Fragment fragment;
        TabInfo(String tag, Class<?> clazz, Bundle args) {
            this.tag = tag;
            this.clss = clazz;
            this.args = args;
        }
    }

    class TabFactory implements TabContentFactory {

        private final Context mContext;

        /** 
         * @param context 
         */
        public TabFactory(Context context) {
            mContext = context;
        }

        public View createTabContent(String tag) {
            View v = new View(mContext);
            v.setMinimumWidth(0);
            v.setMinimumHeight(0);
            return v;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.relatorio_layout);

        initialiseTabHost();
    }   

    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putString("tab", mTabHost.getCurrentTabTag()); //salva a tabela selecionada
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    private void initialiseTabHost() {
        String id = getIntent().getExtras().getString("id");
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("id", id);
        mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup();
        TabInfo tabInfo = null;
        RelatorioPontos.addTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Dados").setIndicator("Dados"),
                (tabInfo = new TabInfo("Dados", DadosPonto.class, args)));
        this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
        RelatorioPontos.addTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Analises").setIndicator("Analises"),
                (tabInfo = new TabInfo("Analises", AnalisesPonto.class, args)));
        this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
        RelatorioPontos.addTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Multimidia").setIndicator("Multimidia"),
                (tabInfo = new TabInfo("Multimidia", ArquivosMultimidia.class, args)));
        this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
    }

    /** 
     * @param activity
     * @param tabHost
     * @param tabSpec
     * @param clss
     * @param args 
     */
    private static void addTab(RelatorioPontos activity, TabHost tabHost, TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, TabInfo tabInfo) {
        tabSpec.setContent(activity.new TabFactory(activity));
        String tag = tabSpec.getTag();

        tabInfo.fragment = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
        if (tabInfo.fragment != null && !tabInfo.fragment.isDetached()) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.detach(tabInfo.fragment);
            ft.commit();
            activity.getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
        }

        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
    }

    public void onTabChanged(String tag) {
        TabInfo newTab = this.mapTabInfo.get(tag);
        if (mLastTab != newTab) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            if (mLastTab != null) {
                if (mLastTab.fragment != null) {
                    ft.detach(mLastTab.fragment);
                }
            }
            if (newTab != null) {
                if (newTab.fragment == null) {
                    newTab.fragment = Fragment.instantiate(this, newTab.clss.getName(), newTab.args);
                    ft.add(R.id.realtabcontent, newTab.fragment, newTab.tag);
                } else {
                    ft.attach(newTab.fragment);
                }
            }

            mLastTab = newTab;
            ft.commit();
            this.getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
        }
    }

}
```

And here is the DadosPonto when I put the TextViews

```
public class DadosPonto extends Fragment {

    public TextView idPonto;
    public TextView idUser;
    public TextView pontoNome;
    public TextView dtCampo;
    public TextView projeto;
    public TextView UTMEste;
    public TextView UTMNorte;
    public TextView UTMFuso;
    public TextView UTMHemisferio;
    public TextView latDec;
    public TextView longDec;
    public TextView altitude;
    public TextView localidade;
    public TextView outrasUG;
    public TextView descPonto;
    public TextView complemento;
    public TextView equipe;
    public TextView fonteUG;

    Ponto ponto = new Ponto();

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        getArguments().getString("id");

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dados_ponto_layout, container, false);

        idPonto = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.idPonto);
        idUser = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.idUser);
        pontoNome = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nomePonto);
        dtCampo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dtCampo);
        projeto = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.projeto);
        UTMEste = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.utmEste);
        UTMNorte = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.utmNorte);
        UTMFuso = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.utmFuso);
        UTMHemisferio = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.utmHemisferio);
        latDec = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.latDec);
        longDec = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.longDec);
        altitude = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.altitude);
        localidade = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.localidade);
        outrasUG = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.outrasUG);
        descPonto = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.descPonto);
        complemento = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.complemento);
        equipe = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.equipe);
        fonteUG = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fonteUG);

        idPonto.setText(ponto.getIdPonto());
        idUser.setText(ponto.getIdUsuario());
        pontoNome.setText(ponto.getPontoNome());
        dtCampo.setText(ponto.getDtCampo());
        projeto.setText(ponto.getProjeto());
        UTMEste.setText(String.valueOf(ponto.getUTMEste()));
        UTMNorte.setText(String.valueOf(ponto.getUTMNorte()));
        UTMFuso.setText(ponto.getUTMFuso());
        UTMHemisferio.setText(ponto.getUTMHemisferio());
        latDec.setText(String.valueOf(ponto.getLatDec()));
        longDec.setText(String.valueOf(ponto.getLongDec()));
        altitude.setText(ponto.getAltitude());
        localidade.setText(ponto.getLocalidade());
        outrasUG.setText(ponto.getOutrasUG());
        descPonto.setText(ponto.getDescPonto());
        complemento.setText(ponto.getComplement());
        equipe.setText(ponto.getEquipe());
        fonteUG.setText(ponto.getFonteUG());

        return view;
    }

}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong in this code, please help me.

(EDIT)
Here is the Ponto class where I have the getters and setters:

```
public class Ponto {
    /**Identificador do ponto. Composto pela sigla + número atual (exemplo: XXX0000) */
    private String idPonto;
    /**Identificador do usuário */
    private int idUsuario;
    /** Nome do ponto. Mesma regra de nomenclatura que o id do ponto*/
    private String pontoNome = null;
    /**Data do campo */
    private String dtCampo;
    /** Projeto selecionado para esse ponto */
    private int projeto = 0;
    /** Coordenada de UTM Este */
    private double UTMEste = 0;
    /** Coordenada de UTM Norte */
    private double UTMNorte = 0;
    /** Coordenada de UTM Fuso */
    private int UTMFuso = 0;
    /** Hemisfério da UTM */
    private String UTMHemisferio = "S";
    /** Coordenadas decimais / geográficas para latitude. Necessárias para conversão para grau-minuto-segundo */
    private double latDec = 0;
    /** Coordenadas decimais / geográficas para longitude. Necessárias para conversão para grau-minuto-segundo */
    private double longDec = 0;
    /** Altitude para coordenadas */
    private int altitude = 0;
    /** Informações de descrição da localidade */
    private String outrasUG = "NENHUMA";
    /** Descrição do ponto */
    private String descPonto = " - ";
    /** Complemento de descrição do ponto */
    private String complement = " - ";
    /**descrição do localidade do ponto */
    private String localidade = " - ";
    /** participantes da atividade de compo*/
    private String equipe = " - ";
    /** ação a ser executada na exportação*/
    private String acao = "";
    /***/

    private String fonteUG;

    private ArrayList<PontoUnGeologica> unidadeGeologica;

    /**Analíse de Campo do Ponto*/
    private AnaliseCampo analiseCampo;


    public Ponto() {
        dtCampo = new Date().toString();
        analiseCampo = new AnaliseCampo();
        unidadeGeologica = new ArrayList<PontoUnGeologica>();

    }

    public String getPontoNome() {
        return pontoNome;
    }

    public void setPontoNome(String pontoNome) {
        this.pontoNome = pontoNome;
    }

    public String getDtCampo() {
        return dtCampo;
    }

    public void setDtCampo(String dtCampo) {
        this.dtCampo = dtCampo;
    }

    public double getUTMEste() {
        return UTMEste;
    }

    public void setUTMEste(double uTMEste) {
        UTMEste = uTMEste;
    }

    public double getUTMNorte() {
        return UTMNorte;
    }

    public void setUTMNorte(double uTMNorte) {
        UTMNorte = uTMNorte;
    }

    public int getUTMFuso() {
        return UTMFuso;
    }

    public void setUTMFuso(int uTMFuso) {
        UTMFuso = uTMFuso;
    }

    public double getLatDec() {
        return latDec;
    }

    public void setLatDec(double latDec) {
        this.latDec = latDec;
    }


    public double getLongDec() {
        return longDec;
    }
    public void setLongDec(double longDec) {
        this.longDec = longDec;
    }


    public String getUTMHemisferio() {
        return UTMHemisferio;
    }
    public void setUTMHemisferio(String uTMHemisferio) {
        UTMHemisferio = uTMHemisferio;
    }


    public int getAltitude() {
        return altitude;
    }
    public void setAltitude(int altitude) {
        this.altitude = altitude;
    }


    public String getOutrasUG() {
        return outrasUG;
    }
    public void setOutrasUG(String outrasUG) {
        this.outrasUG = outrasUG;
    }


    public String getDescPonto() {
        return descPonto;
    }
    public void setDescPonto(String descPonto) {
        this.descPonto = descPonto;
    }


    public String getComplement() {
        return complement;
    }
    public void setComplement(String complemento) {
        this.complement = complemento;
    }


    public String getIdPonto() {
        return idPonto;
    }

    public void setIdPonto(String idPonto) {
        this.idPonto = idPonto;
    }

    public AnaliseCampo getAnaliseCampo() {
        return analiseCampo;
    }

    public void setAnaliseCampo(AnaliseCampo analiseCampo) {
        this.analiseCampo = analiseCampo;
    }

    public int getProjeto() {
        return projeto;
    }
    public void setProjeto(int projeto) {
        this.projeto = projeto;
    }

    public int getIdUsuario() {
        return idUsuario;
    }
    public void setIdUsuario(int idUsuario) {
        this.idUsuario = idUsuario;
    }


    public String getLocalidade() {
        return localidade;
    }
    public void setLocalidade(String localidade) {
        this.localidade = localidade;
    }


    public String getEquipe() {
        return equipe;
    }
    public void setEquipe(String equipe) {
        this.equipe = equipe;
    }


    public ArrayList<PontoUnGeologica> getUnidadeGeologica() {
        return unidadeGeologica;
    }

    public void setUnidadeGeologica(ArrayList<PontoUnGeologica> unidadeGeologica) {
        this.unidadeGeologica = unidadeGeologica;
    }

    public String getAcao() {
        return acao;
    }

    public void setAcao(String acao) {
        this.acao = acao;
    }

    public String getFonteUG() {
        return fonteUG;
    }

    public void setFonteUG(String fonteUG) {
        this.fonteUG = fonteUG;
    }

}
```

Comment: can you post those "get" methods that are called in the setText?

Comment: what "get" in particular you want me to post?

Comment: Any one really, from looking quickly at the fragment part it seems that the textview is there but with an empty string so it appears to not be there is my assumption. Have you tried a hard coded string just to see if the text view is there?

Comment: ok I updated the question with the class where I have the getters

Comment: It appears that you are setting the text to null/empty strings, that is why it looks like they are not there.

Comment: Hum I see, I think I know what I'm doing wrong and I'll try to fix it

Comment: Well I changed the code to get the Ponto data from PontoDAO but it still not working here is the code I added:
String id = getArguments().getString("id");
View view...
PontoDAO pdao = new PontoDAO(c);
ponto = pdao.retornaPonto(id);